# Braintree, How do I delete a users credit card with the nonce from the client?

Tags: ruby, braintree, braintree-rails, braintree-sandbox

Server side there is a function to delete a payment method (`result = Braintree::PaymentMethod.delete("the_token")`) but it takes a payment method token. How do I get the payment methods token with the nonce from the client?

edit: I'm not using the drop in UI. I have a custom list of credit cards the user has (using the Javascript v3 SDK). I want to have a button to delete cards. The JS SDK dosnt give the credit cards token, just a nonce. What is the process for turning the data available to the client into something I can use to delete the card on the server?

edit2: The list of credit cards on the clent side uses the [VaultManager](https://braintree.github.io/braintree-web/current/VaultManager.html#fetchPaymentMethods) from the JavaScript v3 SDK. It returns a [fetchPaymentMethodsPayload](https://braintree.github.io/braintree-web/current/VaultManager.html#~fetchPaymentMethodsPayload).

This is the client side code:

```
_loadPaymentMethods() {
    this.paymentService.getBraintreeToken().then( token => {
      this.braintreeClient.create({
        authorization: token
      }, (clientErr, clientInstance) => {

        if (clientErr) {
          // Handle error in client creation
          return;
        }

        var options = {
          client: clientInstance,
        };

        this.vaultManager.create(options, (err, vaultInstance) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
          }
          vaultInstance.fetchPaymentMethods({ defaultFirst: true }, (err, paymentMethods) => {
            paymentMethods.forEach( paymentMethod => {
              if(paymentMethod.type == 'CreditCard') {
                this.cards.push(paymentMethod);
                if(paymentMethod.default) {
                  this.card = paymentMethod;
                }
              }
            });
          });
        });

      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: A [payment method nonce](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/overview#payment-method-nonce) generally does not correspond to a vaulted [payment method](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/payment-method). The nonce represents temporary payment information to be consumed. The main exception to this is if you're using the Drop-in UI and including a [`customer_id` in the client token](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/drop-in/javascript/#customer-id). Can you edit your question to say whether you are using the Drop-in UI's auto-vaulting capability?

Comment: Assuming you're generating your custom list of the user's credit cards by finding the [customer object](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/customer), you can access the [payment method token](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/payment-method) through the [customer's payment methods attribute](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/customer/#payment_methods).  If you're not populating your payment methods in this way, can you add your code that generates the list of the user's credit cards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

If using [VaultManager](https://braintree.github.io/braintree-web/current/VaultManager.html#~fetchPaymentMethodsPayload) on the client-side to populate your cards, you will not have the functionality to allow a user to delete one of those cards. The reason for this goes back to what you said, that nonces are what's returned on the `fetchPaymentMethodsPayload` method. `VaultManager` can populate a `nonce` that's associated with an already created card, since it's only passing that nonce into a `Transaction.sale() call`. Since the nonce is populated when the form is rendered, you can not search for that nonce compared to a payment method in the vault, since it will not exist previously and nonces are meant for one time use. This is why nonces aren't passed into `PaymentMethod.find()` calls.

To accomplish your task you would need to build out custom logic that mimics what Vault Manager does; however, would need to returns the tokens. One way would be as mentioned in my comment: by finding the [customer object](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/customer/ruby) and grabbing the [customer's payment methods](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/customer/ruby#payment_methods), and then pulling out the tokens associated with those payment methods.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that when you create a payment method with same creds, it won't get duplicated. So it's kinda like "find or create", you can then use that result to get the token and then do a `gateway.payment_method.delete( result.payment_method.token )`